# Error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0

Tags: java, swing

```
dm = (DefaultTableModel) jTable2.getModel();
int row = dm.getRowCount();
getTable obj1 = new getTable(); 
System.out.println("list size " + stu.size());
for (int i = 0; i <= stu.size(); i++ ) {
    obj1 = (getTable)stu.get(i);
    dm.setValueAt(obj1.getStrName(),row , 0);
    dm.setValueAt(obj1.getStrFname(),row , 1); 
    dm.setValueAt(obj1.getRoll_num(),row , 2);
    dm.setValueAt(obj1.getAddr1(),row , 3);
    dm.setValueAt(obj1.getAddr2(),row , 4);
    dm.setValueAt(obj1.getPhoneNumber(),row , 5);
    dm.setValueAt(obj1.getEmail(),row , 6);
    dm.setValueAt(obj1.getDept(),row , 7);
}
```

I am new at coding I just got stuck on this problem for quite sometime now, What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [tour], then learn [ask] a good question which involves a [mcve] and don't forget to post your exception here and indent your code correctly

Comment: @Frakcool Thanks and will work on it.

Answer (score 3):

`ArrayList.size()` returns the no of elements in the list.

Also ArrayList starts with the index 0.

So to iterate through `n` events in an `ArrayList` we have to iterate till `ArrayList[n-1]`.

So avoid the `<=` condition in loop and put `<`.

Answer (score 1):

This `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0` means that the index 0 is not a valid index for your array, which in turn means that your array is empty.